# SQL 1064 error - broken script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

would someone be able to help with a very annoying database error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('0', 'Warning:')' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO possession_new (id, ) VALUES ('0', 'Warning:')"

My code:

```
John, thanks for identifying this. I can't seem to identify why the $pos variable has no value? 

          '$pos = '';
                foreach($html_base->find('td[width=120]') as $k)
                {
                    if(trim($k->plaintext) != '')
                    {
                        $pos .= 'poss_'.str_replace(' ', '_', substr(trim($k->plaintext), 0, -1)).", ";
                    }
                }
                
                $pos_detail = '';
                foreach($html_base->find('td[class=color_text_view]b') as $k)
                {
                    $pos_detail .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($k->plaintext))."', ";
                }
                
                foreach($html_base->find('td[width=250], td[width=251], td[width=621]') as $td)
                {
                    $input = $td->find('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], input[name=manager], textarea');
                    foreach($input as $in)
                    {
                        if($in->getAttribute('name') == 'manager')
                        {
                            $pos_detail .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($td->plaintext))."', ";
                            continue;
                        }
                        elseif($in->hasAttribute('rows'))
                        {
                            $pos_detail .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($td->plaintext))."', ";
                            continue;
                        }
                        
                        elseif($in->getAttribute('name') == 'critical')
                        {
                            if($in->hasAttribute('checked'))
                            {
                                $pos_detail .= "'Y', ";
                                continue;
                            }
                            elseif(!$in->hasAttribute('checked'))
                            {
                                $pos_detail .= "'N', ";
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        elseif($in->getAttribute('name') == 'library')
                        {
                            if($in->hasAttribute('checked'))
                            {
                                $pos_detail .= "'Y', ";
                                continue;
                            }
                            elseif(!$in->hasAttribute('checked'))
                            {
                                $pos_detail .= "'N', ";
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $pos_detail .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($in->getAttribute('value')))."', ";
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    if(!$td->find('input') && $td->previousSibling()=='<td width="120">PICOP:</td>')
                    {
                        $pos_detail .= "'', ";
                    }
                }
                
                $pos = substr($pos, 0, -2);
                $pos_detail = substr($pos_detail, 0, -2);
                
                $possession = "INSERT INTO possession_new ".
                       "(id, $pos) ".
                       "VALUES ".
                       "('0', $pos_detail)";
                $this->db->query($possession);
                $possession_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();'
```

the script is used for an internal system I build which feeds from another site from my login which is owned by my company. I have full permission to use this curl script, the script has worked for the last 12 months however, its suddenly developed teething issues....

Any advice?

Comment: This has nothing to do with cURl - please edit your title.

Answer (score 3):

The error message shows your error clearly: `$pos` has no value which breaks your query. Now you need to figure out *why*.

```
INSERT INTO possession_new (id, ) VALUES ('0', 'Warning:')"
                             ^^^^^
                            MISSING
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a column name after the column name `id`

INSERT INTO possession_new (id, ) VALUES ('0', 'Warning:')"

You are missing the name of the column that `Warning` should be inserted to, e.g. something like

INSERT INTO possession_new (id, myColumnName) VALUES ('0', 'Warning:')"